# Sed Error : sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

I have file .config with line : 
*projdir name_of_the_projdir*

I need to with replace name_of_the_projdir with my own variable. I try to do it with

```
sed -i 's/^projdir .*$/projdir '$projdir'/' .le/.config
```

but i get error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'
```

anyone know what to do ?... i try to replace first ' and last with " and first and alst / with @ . But still not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that error because the `/` delimiters you use with the substitute command are clashing with the directory separators. You can change them to something else:

```
sed -i 's!^projdir .*$!projdir '$projdir'!' .le/.config
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't considering the slashes in my variables (they're URLs in my case) and it was driving me nuts that no amount of escaping things everywhere else was helping anything.